# User input from the command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, command-line

I have to make a program that is called from the command line like this

```
python3 hello.py <name>
```

I was able to get it done like this, but it still asks for the name:

```
def hello(name: str):
    if name == None or name == '':
        return 'Hello, World!'
    else:
        return 'Hello, ' + name


    if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hello(input("How can I call you?"))
```

Comment: this does not use the parameter provided on the commandline but asks for an input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sys.argv` [Check the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

```
import sys
print_hello(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Editted, used wrong index

Comment: What if I want to input multiple arguments? I've tried to use "argv" as an argument ,and called it with a method that has an "*args" parameter, but it throws an error which says: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Comment: `sys.argv` returns a list where the first element is the name of the script. You can just iterate this list from `[1:]` and pass that to the method.